Generation of paths on a sphere in Blender
There is a code (which I will provide below) generated using ChatGPT. This code generates a sphere (an icosphere with a high subdivision count, though you can use a sphere with a higher subdivision count) and evenly distributes 32 small named spheres on it. Then, it generates the shortest path from sphere a1 to b6, which are the two most distant spheres from each other. Up until this point, the code works fine.
However, there are issues after this. I need the paths from a1 to all other spheres, and they must meet the following requirements:

The path lengths should be as close as possible to the length of the path from a1 to b6.

The paths should not intersect with other spheres, meaning that the path from a1 to a3, for example, should not intersect with any other spheres except for a1 and a3. Ideally, the paths should also maintain some mandatory distance from other spheres and from each other. However, the intersection of the starting and ending spheres is mandatory.

The paths should not intersect with each other. They can overlap at the start, but they should not cross each other later on.

The path can bend, but the bends should    referably not be sharp (90 degrees or more), and the number of bends should also be limited (for example, no more than 10). This is where a working algorithm to find the required bends is needed.

The path must lie on the sphere. It doesn't have to follow the sphere's grid exactly, but it should stay on the sphere's surface.


I have tried various approaches, but usually the code doesn't meet all the requirements, and the generated paths are very unattractive. Perhaps conditional Q-learning should be tried, but it's unclear how to set it up. Below is an example of how the code builds paths (without deviations) and how I would like to see them (the path I drew myself for approximation, though the lengths may not match exactly).



Here's code:


import bpy

import math

import mathutils



bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')

bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False)



bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=6, radius=1)

sphere = bpy.context.object

sphere.name = "MainSphere"



bpy.ops.object.shade_smooth()



bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')



num_points = 32



phi = (1 + math.sqrt(5)) / 2



def calculate_A(n):

    if n == 1:

        return 1

    elif n == 2:

        return 4

    else:

        A = [1, 4]

        for i in range(2, n):

            A.append(A[i-1] + A[i-2])

        return A[n-1]



def calculate_g(N):

    k = math.floor(math.log(N / 1.5) / math.log(phi))

    if k % 2 == 0:

        return 3 - phi

    else:

        j = (k + 7) // 2

        A_j_next = calculate_A(j + 1)

        A_j = calculate_A(j)

        return A_j_next / A_j



def delini_sphere_points(num_points):

    points = []

    for k in range(num_points):

        g_n = calculate_g(k + 1)

        theta = math.acos(1 - 2 * (k + 0.5) / num_points)

        phi_angle = math.pi * (1 + 5**0.5) * (k + 1)

        x_pos = math.sin(theta) * math.cos(phi_angle)

        y_pos = math.sin(theta) * math.sin(phi_angle)

        z_pos = math.cos(theta)

        points.append((x_pos, y_pos, z_pos))

    return points



points = delini_sphere_points(num_points)



sphere_objects = []

for idx, point in enumerate(points):

    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=0.04, location=point)

    small_sphere = bpy.context.object

    letter = chr(97 + (idx // 26))

    number = (idx % 26) + 1

    small_sphere.name = f"{letter}{number}"

    sphere_objects.append(small_sphere)



a1_location = sphere_objects[0].location

b6_location = sphere_objects[31].location



def distance(point1, point2):

    return (point1 - point2).length



def create_constrained_path(start, end, num_segments, max_deviation_angle=90):

    path_coords = [start]

    prev_direction = (end - start).normalized()

    

    for i in range(1, num_segments - 1):

        t = i / (num_segments - 1)

        interpolated_point = start.lerp(end, t)

        direction = (interpolated_point - start).normalized()

        

        angle = prev_direction.angle(direction)

        if math.degrees(angle) > max_deviation_angle:

            direction = prev_direction

        

        prev_direction = direction

        path_coords.append(start + direction * distance(start, end) * t)

    

    path_coords.append(end)

    return path_coords



def normalize_to_sphere(path_coords):

    return [point.normalized() for point in path_coords]



num_segments = 35

path_coords_a1_b6 = create_constrained_path(a1_location, b6_location, num_segments)



path_coords_a1_b6 = normalize_to_sphere(path_coords_a1_b6)



def create_tube_from_path(path_coords, radius=0.05):

    curve_data = bpy.data.curves.new(name="PathCurve", type='CURVE')

    curve_data.dimensions = '3D'

    spline = curve_data.splines.new(type='POLY')

    spline.points.add(count=len(path_coords) - 1)

    

    for i, vertex in enumerate(path_coords):

        spline.points[i].co = (vertex.x, vertex.y, vertex.z, 1)



    curve_object = bpy.data.objects.new("PathCurveObject", curve_data)

    bpy.context.scene.collection.objects.link(curve_object)

    

    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    curve_object.select_set(True)

    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = curve_object

    bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH')

    

    bpy.ops.object.modifier_add(type='BEVEL')

    bevel = curve_object.modifiers["Bevel"]

    bevel.width = radius

    bevel.segments = 4



    return curve_object



create_tube_from_path(path_coords_a1_b6, radius=0.05)



distance_a1_b6 = distance(a1_location, b6_location)



def create_paths_to_all_spheres():

    for idx, sphere_object in enumerate(sphere_objects):

        if sphere_object != sphere_objects[0]:

            path_length = distance(a1_location, sphere_object.location)

            num_segments = max(int((path_length / distance_a1_b6) * len(path_coords_a1_b6)), 30)



           

            path_coords = create_constrained_path(a1_location, sphere_object.location, num_segments)

            

           

            path_coords = normalize_to_sphere(path_coords)

            

          

            create_tube_from_path(path_coords, radius=0.05)



create_paths_to_all_spheres()

